# Question about hyperplane divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

I'm not sure how to solve this question.

Clearly, $div (z) - div (L)$ is a principal divisor, so they are linearly equivalent, so as the degree of a principal divisor is $0$, we get that $deg(div(z)) = deg(div(L))$.

But aren't $div(z)$ and $div(L)$ principal divisors?

So their degree should also be zero?

But I'm meant to prove that $deg(div(L)) = a$.

What mistake have I made here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is clear to you that $\mathrm{div}(z)-\mathrm{div}(L)$ is principal, then this is most of the solution. However it's not true that $\mathrm{div}(z)$ or $\mathrm{div}(L)$ are principal. Sure, it might *seem* like $\mathrm{div}(z)$ comes from the rational function $z$, but this isn't actually a well defined rational function because we're in $\mathbb P^2$ and $z$ is not invariant under scaling. A rational function on projective space is a homogeneous rational function of degree zero. This means that the rational functions on $\mathbb P^2$ are given by expressions of the form $P/Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree.

Similarly, $\mathrm{div}(L)$ is not principal.

To be absolutely clear, $\mathrm{div}(z)-\mathrm{div}(L)$ is principal because it is the divisor of the rational function $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{z}{ax+by+cz},$$ where $ax+by+cz=0$ describes the line $L$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. One more question to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, why exactly does deg(div(z)) = a?

Comment: Because the curve has degree $a$, so the intersection with any line will contain $a$ points (with multiplicity).